# fullPage.js window on resize issue

Tags: fullpage.js

First time using FullPage/js and its great. nearly finished the site, had issues with scripts but finally got there.

I do have one issue which i can not fix. On resizing window the page does not align or scaffold the pages correctly unless i refresh.

so i am trying this to resolve it:

JS

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
                 $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
                     if(fullPageCreated === false) {
                        fullPageCreated = true;
                });
```

fullpage.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Initializing fullpage.js
        initialize(false);
        function initialize(hasScrollBar){
            $('#fullPage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'],
                controlArrows: true,
                menu: '#menu',
                //resize:true,
                easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190)',
                animateAnchor: true,
                slidesNavigation: false,
                navigation: false,
                fadingEffect: 'slides',
                fadingEffectKey: 'YWhpbXNhaW52ZXN0bWVudHMuY29tX00zMlptRmthVzVuUldabVpXT??????',
                parallax: 'sections',
                parallaxKey: 'YWhpbXNhaW52ZXN0bWVudHMuY29tX09NMWNHRnlZV3hzWVhnP???????',
                parallaxOptions: {
                    type: 'reveal',
                    percentage: 50,
                    property: 'translate',
                },
                scrollingSpeed: 600,
                autoScrolling: true,
                scrollBar: hasScrollBar,
                fitToSection:true,
                scrollOverflow: true, 
                verticalCentered: true,

                });

                //onLoad Scripts !NOT WORKING YET FIX!
                //var fileref=document.createElement('script');
                //fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
                //fileref.setAttribute("src", 
                   'http://domain/js/slick-slider.js');
                $( window ).resize(function() {
                 $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
                     if(fullPageCreated === false) {
                        fullPageCreated = true;
                });
                //Silentmove links
                $(document).on('click', '#silentp1', function(){
                  $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('page1', 0);
                }); 
                $(document).on('click', '#silentp1-2', function(){
                  $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('page1', 1);
                }); 
                $(document).on('click', '#silentp1-3', function(){
                  $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('page1', 2);
                });     
                $(document).on('click', '#silentp1-4', function(){
                  $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('page1', 3);
                });             

                //fadeout bckgrnd on scroll
                // $(window).scroll(function() {
                //  $(".parallax-mirror img").css({
                //  'opacity': 1 - (($(this).scrollTop()) / 250)
                // }); });

}

});
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of fullPage.js 2.9.6? And the [latest of scrolloverflow 0.0.5](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/dev/vendors/scrolloverflow.js)?

Comment: Hi Alvaro, yes im using both of those, but my file is fullpage.extension.min.js

Comment: Seems that if using tab content and the <div> has position:absolute, fullpage.js will not be able to resize correctly.

Comment: Sorry I can't tell without an isolated reproduction. And I don't know what you mean by "using tab content" or even where is your absolute div.

Comment: I have tried to load it into jsfiddle but it breaks for some reason. I have been searching for an alternative. I did find this: http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/2333/  but require it in reverse. so the tabcontant is inside a slide of a section. I did try to use bootstrap nav, tabs apear but no content.

Comment: bug with using parallax and fade extension together